# How to prevent windows from using all RAM when running the system for an extended period of time?

Tags: windows, memory, task-manager, swap

I own two up to date computers with windows 10, with fairly different hardware, on both of them, windows fills the ram (99-100%) over time, usually after a month of run time.
The first uses a hard drive; the second uses a SSD with low capacity + a hard drive.

When the ram is full, my programs are extremely slow and often freeze. When that happens, disk use also reaches 100% most of the time.
I've found a temporary way to make my system usable, that is to launch a very ram intensive program multiple times, such as a video game, after leaving the computer running and closing the process, I have more ram available, and the computer is again usable.

Ram use and disk space on the task manager don't add up as you could imagine.
This isn't due to malware; this is purely due to windows mismanaging ram.

Windows is using ram I don't want to be used, and I would like to make sure every unused ram is not used without my approval.

Changing the OS, hardware, or shutting down the system often aren't options for me.

Comment: Wagnardsoft's *Intelligent standby list cleaner (ISLC)* can help free memory, if the issue is due to Windows garbage collectio/reallocation issues, https://www.wagnardsoft.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1256 (though it won't ameliorate memory leaks). It seems to help with memory intensive tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a memory leak, although a very small one. Such a problem
is very hard to detect.

Almost the only tool that can help is
[RAMMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap).
You should consult it whenever memory is full, although understanding
the numbers is not always easy. You should also check in Task Manager
if the swap space is increasing when it happens.

As the leak in this case is very small and takes a whole month to
build up, the problem is more of an annoyance. The simplest solution
is to do a cold reboot, perhaps once a week.
Note that hibernation or sleep doesn't cause the used up memory to be
released, only cold reboot will reinitialize the memory allocation.

Comment: How to look at the swap space in task manager? I've been looking at RAMMap, task manager, resource monitor but I haven't been able to succeed so far to identify the issue. The processes that are common to the computers, except windows itself, are malwarebytes and avira which are also up to date, keepass, "7+ taskbar tweaker", chrome and brave browser. Sadly rebooting isn't an option. I thought that maybe preventing windows to "use unused ram" would solve the issue.

Comment: You may find some info in Task Manager, Performance, Memory. Windows memory management is very good - an intervention may only make matters worse. Why reboot isn't an option?

Comment: Because I don't want to take the risk to lose some data that are in ram and I don't have the time to save or sort that data (countless notepads, spreadsheets, internet tabs with data in ram, dev environment with multiple programs, folders, files to open which I only have in my memory, etc). Plus the fact that my main computer takes hours to launch and the fear that it might not reboot while I have urgent work to do ,which already happen. Not worth it. Just want my system to run and to not use unused ram.

Comment: In the task manager, it says 'used (compressed)':31.6 GB; Available 450 MB; validated 108/124 GB; Cache 437 MB; Paged 1.8 GB; Non paged pool 1.7 GB. Total used 31.6/31.9 GB (99%). All visible processes use less than 10 GB out of 32 GB. And disk use often at 100%, very often because of microsoft processes (system, update, services, etc)

Comment: Your numbers show that you're really starved for RAM and Windows has started to compress RAM in an attempt to reduce usage. In an environment that is so choke-full of applications a memory leak is almost impossible to trace. With the boot taking hours, I suggest to envisage moving to a new computer, or to increase your RAM. However, for example, doubling your RAM may only give you 2 months of peace instead of one. The minimum you can do is to fully update Windows, all drivers and the applications that you use daily.

Comment: Windows doesn't compress ram visibly unless I launch myself a very large program to take back the lost ram. Yes buying a new better computer is planned but the problem will probably happen again considering I'll be using the same system and programs. Windows and programs are already up to date. Considering I run basic and popular programs it's hard to think of that as the issue. Drivers are different between the 2 computers. To me it seems that the problem is the "unused ram is wasted ram" opinion that windows seems to have, but I don't know what to do to solve this issue once and for all.

Comment: Windows has no wasted RAM : Even the disk cache is emptied and allocated to applications if the memory is required. Another method for speeding up swaps is having a faster disk, especially SSD, which might make the computer usable for longer. It's better for the new computer to run Windows 11 which is still fully supported, so Windows memory leaks have a better chance of being fixed.

Comment: Considering I have slow drives (hard drives) in both systems; swaps shall be prevented completely in my opinion. As soon as one hard drive is used, the system becomes unusable. So this 2/3 of lost ram would be due to an unknown memory leak and windows cannot do anything about it? that would be unfortunate and surprising to encounter those kinds of issues in the current year

Comment: These kinds of problems have unfortunately always been with us in all operating systems, and there's no magic solution in sight.

Comment: Every byte used in ram comes from a program, why don't the os always categorize clearly what is being used. I doubt the os couldn't prevent a program from using ram if that ram isn't properly "registered". If the os allows ram to be used up to the point where there's 2/3 of the system ram that it cannot display in the task manager, then it seems to be a problem with the os

Comment: Yes, OS and its drivers are often the source of memory leaks, as they cannot be swapped out. Application memory leaks are easier to detect.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Do you happen to know by chance the name of a program that can use large amounts of ram, keep it in use, and release it easily with ideally a graphical interface? Maybe some kind of test tool.

Comment: I don't, but such a program risks hastening the problem rather than be a solution. Cold reboot is really the best solution, if you can organize your working methods accordingly.